# Blue card employer change

Tags: germany

I have a Blue Card issued on (13-09-2018) and valid till (12-09-2022) with residence permit in Berlin. Employer name is not mentioned in the Blue Card and *Zusatzblatt*.

I'm discharged of my duties from previous employer and now I have an offer from another employer based in Nuremberg.

Should I take an appointment for "Change of Employer" process or "Registration of New employer" at the *Ausländerbehörde*?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are still registered in Berlin you only need to apply for "change or employer": https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/dienstleistungen/service.245714.php/dienstleistung/326856/en/ 
If you already moved to Nuremberg and be registered there, than you will need to apply at the responsible immigration office in Nuremberg.